# How to copy a file on linux from a c program exactly

Tags: c, linux, file, copy

With exactly i mean preserving holes in sparse files and all extended attributes catching situations where the target file system does not support them or not fully (for example different EA lengths)? And on mounted NTFS filesystems it should work with alternate streams too. Preserving as much file attributes as possible.

Need callbacks for progress GUI too. This seems to be difficult an maintenance hell, so i guess there is something already useable like the SHFileOperation on Windows.

I looked at GLIB and they are doing it in the most simple way with open/read/write/close sequence.

Comment: I'm sure you'll get a good answer, so I won't post source. I would open the source file read/binary and the output file write/binary, and just transfer the contents.

Comment: on linux, `sendfile` is a better option, though I have no idea how it handles files with holes in it. is there an API to test for holes?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: there is lseek(2) and SEEK_DATA/SEEK_HOLE in recent kernels (since 3.1)

Comment: @Octopusgrabbus: A file is more then it's data stream. I thought i made this clear. 90% of the solution i found so far are bad and lacking.

Answer (score 1):

*sendfile* doesn't handle sparse files at all, at least on Linux 4.4 and earlier. Starting from Linux 4.5 there is a new system call [copy_file_range](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html) which hides all the details for you.

For earlier versions, here is [my working example](https://github.com/SkyLandTW/JXTN/blob/master/jxtn-core-unix/src-jni/files2.c) of copying file contents with holes, by *lseek* and *SEEK_HOLE*. It's different from the implementation in *cp*, which instead reads everything from source and skip all-zero blocks, thus being to create holes in destination but still wastes time reading holes from the source. However, it's very possible that some file systems don't support *SEEK_HOLE* even through they already support sparse file, in that case my code would end up creating non-sparse files.

As for extended attributes, you really have to call *listxattr* and then copy each extended attributes by *getxattr*/*setxattr* by yourself.

Nano timestamp can be set by *utimensat*/futimens*

Comment: So linux is slowly getting better. Unix fanboys never accept that they are technically behind Windows for almost 2 decades.

Comment: Change is always slower in the open source model where there are different groups of devs responsible for different layers (kernel core, driver, libc, system program etc). But at least you can change whatever you want if you're willing to.